# Problems with PSCredential

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a script to connect to MicrosoftTeams and change some parameters for users.

In my first attempt I created a simple script with

```
Import-Module MicrosoftTeams

$login = Get-Credential
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $login 

$mail = Read-Host
$phone = Read-Host

Set-CsUser -Identity $mail -EnterpriseVoiceEnabled $true -HostedVoiceMail $false -OnPremLineURI tel:$phone
Grant-CsOnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy -Identity $mail -PolicyName ""
Get-CsOnlineUser -Identity $mail | Select UserPrincipalName, DisplayName, RegistrarPool, OnlineVoiceRFoutingPolicy, LineURI, OnPremLineURI, EnterpriseVoiceEnabled, HostedVoicemail

Write-Host "done"
Read-Host
```

Now the problem with that was the execution, the script didn't wait until it was connected to Teams and directly asked for $mail etc. And at the end it showed me the output of "Connect-MicrosoftTeams" and never displayed anything from "Get-CsOnlineUser".

So I figured I have to use Jobs. So I added

```
$login = Get-Credential
$connect = Start-Job {Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $args} -ArgumentList $login 
Wait-Job $connect
```

but this fails, Receive-Job shows me this output.

```
Cannot convert 'System.Management.Automation.PSCredential' to the type 'System.Management.Automation.PSCredential' required by parameter 'Credential'. Specified method is not supported.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Connect-MicrosoftTeams], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.TeamsCmdlets.Powershell.Connect.ConnectMicrosoftTeams
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

I'm confused.

Comment: I tried your initial script and I got it working by adding `| Out-Null` to the line with `Connect-MicrosoftTeams`. Can you check and confirm? Also a hint: Add `-Prompt 'anything'` to your `Read-Host` so you can easily notice which cmdlet is currently running

Comment: `Connect-MicrosoftTeams` should block execution until you are connected. Output that is not explicitly piped to Format-* or Out-* is collected for 400ms. This is why the Connect-MicrosoftTeams output appears at the end of the script. I don't suggest using the Job cmdlets. What happens if you manually run your first script one line at a time? Copy each line and paste it into a shell. Check the value of the [-Identity](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/skype/get-csonlineuser?view=skype-ps#examples) parameter. You might find it helpful to use PowerShell ISE or Visual Studio Code.